# How to see when audio playing on mp4

Tags: video, mp4

I have mp4 files that are lengthy videos.  The sound is purposefully only on during important parts.  I'm trying to find a way to visually (or automatically?) find the time periods of the video when there is active audio.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: QuickTime.  Looking into setting up a python script